# CSV upload in Google Maps for ExpressionEngine - PHP error: Filename cannot be empty

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, csv, objective-html

I'm trying to upload a csv file in Google Maps for ExpressionEngine (Objective HTML) and get the output below. On my local installation it imports fine but on the live server I get this error. I can otherwise upload csv files within EE, e.g. within the Assets module. What could prevent the upload within the Google Maps module? I'm testing with a small file with 2 entries and a header row.

---

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Filename: libraries/Gmap_import.php

Line Number: 634

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Filename: libraries/Gmap_import.php

Line Number: 636

can not load csv file

---

I'm using Google Maps for EE 3.3.8 on EE 2.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in the php error logs it was looking for a /tmp folder above web root so I created that and the upload now works.